# What is "built-in" command in bash

Tags: shell

`cd` is a built-in command in Bash. Is a built-in command or function in Bash the same concept as a built-in command or function in an interpreter language (e.g. Python)?

Is "built-in" a concept of Bash itself?

Does any command that is not a built-in in Bash always have an executable file stored somewhere? Does any built-in always have no executable file stored somewhere?

Comment: The bash builtin commands are clearly defined here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192373/what-are-shell-built-in-commands-in-linux

Comment: I have found one question in our site itself which answers your question. :)

Comment: "the shell executes the command directly, without invoking another program."

Answer (score 1):

In genral, the answer is yes. Builtin meaning they are executed in the `bash` itself, instead of an external command (or function), which `bash` must load then execute,

The same concept also applly to `Python`, which has `cpython` as its interpreter. To run `Python` builtin, you just load `cpython` and type it, like:

```
python3 -c 'print("Hello world!")'
```

No need to import anything.

> Does any command that is not a built-in in Bash always have an
>   executable file stored somewhere?

If your system is `Linux`, you can expect that there always has `GNU coreutils`.

> Does any built-in always have no executable file stored somewhere?

Builtin commands are always executable.

Comment: surely you mean the `print` built-in and not `Python` built-in? Also realize that `print` is a built-in function only as of Python 3. `print` in Python 2 is a statement

Comment: @1_CR: oh, my bad example, fixed it!